# How can a wxpython frame "steal" and "return" focus similar to the Dash app?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I want to make a heads-up display that pops up it's frame, taking focus from the previous application and then gives focus back to that application when it's done.

wxPython frames have `Hide` and `Show` methods that work but don't focus the application. Also, there's `SetFocus` which you'd think would do it but doesn't.

### Update

I found a nasty hack that works. Rather than hide and show the frame, you save the app state and close the app instead of hiding. Then when you want to show again you spark a new one in a new `multiprocessing.Process`. Hardly ideal though. I hope someone has something better.

### Clarification

To clarify, I'm trying to get the keyboard focus, not just to get the frame on top of the stack.

This issue might be specific to OS X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to steal focus by calling `Raise` on the frame. There is the `wx.STAY_ON_TOP` style flag that could also be applied. Then you might be able to just use the frame's `Show` and `Hide` methods to make it work.

Depending on what exactly you want to do, you might take a look at the ToasterBox widget. I can't recall if it actually steals focus, but it just pop up and go away on its own, which is handy in some cases.

Comment: To clarify, I'm trying to get the keyboard focus, not just to get the frame on top of the stack.

Comment: This issue might be specific to OS X.

Comment: After you raise your app (with or without the STAY_ON_TOP) flag, you should then be able to call `SetFocus` on one of the widgets in your frame.

Comment: Yes. The wx.STAY_ON_TOP flag is not necessary. The key is to call `SetFocus` on the widget and not on the frame itself. Thanks.

Comment: Most of the time, the frame cannot really accept focus. The panel definitely cannot unless it does not have any children. If the panel does have children and you call SetFocus on it, then it will pass the focus on to its first child that can accept focus. Not sure why the frame doesn't do that too.